# Cual es el proposito de comparar(Verificar) las versiones de android?

Tags: android

Hola buenas noches estoy empezando en esto de programación y me gustaría saber cual es el propósito de verificar la versión de android que el usuario usa?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
```

> **¿Porque razón se realiza esto?**

gracias de antemano si ven varias preguntas de este tipo similares de mi parte disculpen las molestias jejeje es que quiero encontrar la lógica de la programación en android ya que si algo tiene lógica (que yo se que android la tiene) se entiende y se retiene mejor :).

Comment: bueno probe quitandole ese if pero si o si se requiere que se ponga segun android studio :).

Comment: Podrias colocar más código para explicartelo mejor, pero en general las librerias son versionadas, y cambian, por ejemplo el nombre de las clases, funciones, etc, asi que para mantener la compatibilidad de tu aplicación con otras versiones de android se implementan esas verificaciones.

Comment: ahhh ok muchas gracias amigo bueno si tambien lo imagine creo que es para compatibilidad de de las librerias etc gracias :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme va evolucionando el Android SDK, algunos métodos o clases van quedando obsoletas (`deprecated`), en ocasiones son necesarias las validaciones de API ya que nuestras aplicaciones pueden necesitar funcionar en versiones de sistemas operativos actuales como antiguos.

Por lo tanto un mecanismo para realizar esta diferencia es mediante la clase [Build](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build), sus objetos y constantes definidas.

El objeto:

> [**Build.VERSION_CODES**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES)  es una enumeración de los códigos de
>   versión SDK actualmente conocidos. Estos son los valores que se pueden
>   encontrar en **Build.VERSION.SDK**. Los números de versión aumentan
>   monótonamente con cada versión de la plataforma oficial.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La constante:

> [**Build.VERSION.SDK_INT**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) define la versión SDK del software que se ejecuta
>   actualmente en este dispositivo. Este valor nunca cambia
>   mientras se inicia un dispositivo, pero puede aumentar cuando el
>   fabricante del hardware proporciona una actualización del software en el dispositivo.

---

**Ejemplo**:

El método [isScreenOn()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isScreenOn()) de la clase [PowerManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager), se señala que este método es obsoleto (deprecated) en la [API 20 que es KITKAT_WATCH](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#ApiLevels) y a partir de esta debes usar el método [isInteractive()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isInteractive()) :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto en tu código debes realizar esta diferencia para que funcione el método adecuado para las versiones soportadas:

```
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean isScreenOn;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            isScreenOn = powerManager.isInteractive();
        } else {
            isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();
        }     
    }
```

Ahora bien, es importante saber que esta validación de APIs es necesaria cuando tu proyecto define una versión que incluye cambios en los métodos o clases, es decir tomando como base el ejemplo anterior, podrías tener definido en tu archivo `build.gradle`

```
 compileSdkVersion 27
 targetSdkVersion 27
```

obviamente es necesaria la validación, pero si tuvieras:

```
 compileSdkVersion 19
 targetSdkVersion 19
```

en este caso ya no sería necesaria la validación ya que el cambio ocurre en la version 20:

```
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean isScreenOn;

            isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Como ya se ha dicho, esta comparación sirve para poder implementar algún tipo de código *crucial*  en nuestra app, asegurando la compatibilidad.

Voy a exponer un ejemplo concreto que estoy usando en una app:

Yo uso `TextToSpeech` para leer con voz el texto de un `TextView`. Resulta que **el método `speak` de esta clase evolucionó a partir de la API 21 de Android (se le debe pasar un parámetro adicional)**. Ciertamente, debo implementar el método en su forma evolucionada, pero **debo asegurar que en dispositivos anteriores el código también funcionará**.

Entonces hay que hacer esta comparación:

```
private void leerTexto(String strTexto, String strId) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        //API 21+
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        tts.speak(strTexto, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, bundle, strId);

    } else {
        //API 15-
        HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
        param.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        tts.speak(strTexto, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, param);
    }
}
```

Android Studio me informa de hecho que mi método `speak` (el del `else`)  es obsoleto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debo dejarlo así, o privar a los usuarios con la API 15- de escuchar los textos de voz :)